# How to remove duplicates objects from array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, duplicates

I have an array with objects. How to find objects in this array with same properties?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Check this|: [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/remove-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)